# Riemann integrability of a square of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let, $f(x)$ be continuous in $[0,1]$ such that, $\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}f(x)dx=0$ for $n=0,1,2,3,...$. Then prove that, $\int_{0}^{1}f^{2}(x)dx=0$.

First we apply $1^{st}$ M.V.T. of integral calculus & we get, there exists a constant $c \in [0,1]$ such that, $\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}f(x)dx=f(c)\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}dx=\dfrac{f(c)}{n+1}=0 \implies f(c)=0$.

Thus we get, $\exists$ $c \in [0,1]$ such that $f(c)=0$.

We know that  " If $f(x)$
 is non-negative & continuous in an interval $[a,b]$ & if $\exists$ a constant $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)\gt 0$ then $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\gt 0$.

For this problem, $f^{2}(x)$ is non-negative & continuous in $[a,b]$ & $\exists$ $c \in [0,1]$ such that $f(c)=0$. From this can we say that $\int_{0}^{1}f^{2}(x)dx=0 $ ?

If yes then there is nothing to question & if NOT then how we can solve this problem?

Comment: What? Aren't you assuming that $\int_0^1\!x^nf(x)\,dx = 0$ to begin with? Why are you trying to conclude it?

Comment: Sorry!! It was a mistake...See the edition

Comment: The answer to your question is no. Think $f(x) = x-0.5$. $f(0.5) = 0$, but the integral $\int_0^1\!f^2(x)\,dx > 0$. As the answer below suggests, use Weierstrass approximation to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Weierstrass approximation theorem.

1. From $\int_0^1x^n\,f(x)\,dx=0$ deduce $\int_0^1f(x)\,P(x)\,dx=0$ for any polinomial $P$.
2. Given $\epsilon>0$ there is a polynomial $P$ such that $\sup_{0\le x\le1}|f(x)-P(x)|\le\epsilon$.
3. \begin{align}\int_0^1f^2(x)\,dx&=\int_0^1f(x)(f(x)-P(x))\,dx+\int_0^1f(x)\,P(x)\,dx\\
   &\le\int_0^1|f(x)|\,|(f(x)-P(x))|\,dx\\
   &\le\Bigl(\sup_{0\le x\le1}|f(x)|\Bigr)\,\epsilon.
   \end{align}

Comment: How we can apply it?

Comment: See the extended answer.